# extract from string in c using sscanf

Tags: c, string, character, scanf

I am trying to use sscanf to extract specific values of name and msg from a string `{"username":"ece","says":"hello"}` as following:

```
sscanf(data, "{"\username"\:"\%s"\,"\says"\:"\%s"\}", name, msg);
```

I need 'ece' in name and 'hello' in msg but I am getting ece","says":"hello" in name and msg remains empty.

Comment: it looks like json format. If the case try to use libjson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%s` format stops at the next white space. You need it to stop earlier, at the `'"'`, so you need to use a character set,

```
sscanf(data, "{\"username\":\"%[^\"]\",\"says\":\"%s\"}", name, msg);
                              ^^^^^^
                          read up to the next double quote
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the escape `\` **before** the escaped character.

```
sscanf(data, "{\"username\":\"%s\",\"says\":\"%s\"}", name, msg);
```

And unless there is a white space after the username, all that's in the buffer will be read into `name`.

Use an inverse character set instead of %s, like this `%[^\"]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that %s conversion specification reads input until it reach whitespace character. So, you have all the data after "username" in first variable.

Answer (score 0):

1) in the whole string format you have to correct this `"\` with `\"`. The `\` to mention that that the next character is a special character and `"` is a special character

2) you have to replace `%s` with `%[^\"]` for both `username` and `says`. This above regular expression means that you want to catch string which does not contain `"`. so the catch of the string will stop at the first `"`

```
sscanf(s, "{\"username\":\"%[^\"]\",\"says\":\"%[^\"]\"}", name, msg);
```

Comment: @DanielFischer : I'm having trouble for getting the firs nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf using a single fscanf. I've tried `fscanf(fp,"%*nameserver:%20[^\n]",address);` which return 0 (no result founds); And `address` is empty. (Yes the file as been successfully opened before with fopen).